# Is there any method to implement something like std::is_integral_literal?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Suppose we have two functions:

```
//(1)
template<class T ,
         class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value & ! is_integral_literal<T>::value>::type >
void foo(T)
{
}
```

and

```
//(2)
template<class T ,
         class = typename std::enable_if<is_integral_literal<T>::value>::type >
void foo(const T&)
{
}
```

so

```
int x;
foo(x); //calls (1)
foo(0); //calls (2)
foo(1000); //calls (2)
```

How can I implement `is_integral_literal`? I have made some workaround with `operator "" _int_lit(long long)` which gives me ability to express it with
`foo(0_int_lit)`, but may be there is another solution?

Comment: You misuse SFINAE, as you redefine the function (with different default parameter), correct way is something like : `template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0> void foo(T);`

Comment: How about use `std::integral_constant<int, 0>` (that you can wrap with `operator ""`)?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, I've fixed the implementation, it works with stub `is_integral_literal` for now.

Answer (score 3):

One approach might be to use the fact that an integer literal is an rvalue? Then if your function signature is

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T f(T&& t) {
    return t;
}
```

when called with an rvalue `int` (like a literal), `T` will be deduced as plain `int`, the enable_if condition will hold and this overload will be considered. But when called with an lvalue, for example

```
int i = 0;
f(i);
```

then `T` will be deduced as `int&`, in which case `is_integral<int&>::value` is false and SFINAE will kick in. You can then add a second overload like

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T f(const T& t)
{
    return t;
}
```

to handle the lvalue case (when called with an rvalue both overloads will be considered, but the first will be a better match).

This doesn't *quite* fit the bill completely, as it's still possible to force the first overload with a non-literal by calling `f(std::move(i))`, but I don't know whether this would be a problem for your use-case.

Comment: yes, it is quite suitable for my use case, thank you!